# Mongoose nodejs :¿ Cómo puedo filtrar registros con un campo 'populated', es decir de una relación?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

He intentado usar 'match' en el método de populate pero lo que ocurre es que filtra en el populate pero no en los registros en general. Lo que está pasando con este código es que en el campo populate si cumple con el filtro sale el objeto pero si no sale null pero los registros siguen saliendo sin filtrarse

```
  exports.getSummatory = async function (user_id) {
    try {
        const records = await Movement
        .find({
            user: user_id
        })
        .populate({
            path: 'movementType',
            match: { name: 'Ingresos' }
        })

        return records;
    } catch (e) {
        throw Error(e)
    }
}

//Movement model
   const MovementSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'User'
    },
    movementType: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'MovementType'
    },
    category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    icon: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Icon'
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});
```

Comment: You're at SO en español so please translate into spanish your question, otherwise it will be closed, also please paste as text your code

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea filtrar documentos de una colección de tal forma que al aplicar un proceso de [*poblado* (*populate*)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com), la misma muestre los documentos que únicamente tienen los valores especificados en su campo referenciado.

Sin embargo, al aplicar la condición [`match`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) en la consulta, la misma devuelve todos los documentos, sin tomar en cuenta la condición.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Partiendo de lo que dice la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) (traducción propia):

> La opción *match* no filtra los documentos del *Modelo*. Si no existen documentos que satisfagan la condición, obtendrás documentos del *Modelo* con un `array` vacío en el campo *poblado* (o con un valor `null`).

Dicho esto, es imposible usar `populate` para filtrar los documentos según la condición que pasas a `match`.

Ante esto tienes diferentes opciones, de las cuales enumero al menos 3:

1. Filtrar luego de recibir los datos
2. Usar una consulta en cascada
3. Usar un proceso de agregación

Las he enumerado en orden de preferencia según mi propia experiencia.

**Filtrar luego de recibir los datos**

Podemos aplicar el filtro usando el método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) del tipo [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array) de Javascript, de tal manera que eliminamos todos los documentos cuyo campo `movementType` sea de tipo `null`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const records = await Movement
.find({
  user: user_id
})
.populate({
  path: 'movementType',
  match: { name: 'Ingresos' }
});

const filtered = records.filter(record => record.movementType);

return filtered;
```

Como el método `populate` devuelve un valor `null` sobre los campos que no coinciden con la opción `match`, podemos aplicar el filtro sobre dicho campo en el método `filter`. Sólo aquellos documentos cuyo campo `movementType` sea distinto de `null` serán devueltos y así el `array` llamado `filtered` contendrá la información deseada.

**Usando una consulta en cascada**

Otra forma de lograr lo que te propones es usar una consulta en cascada, ya que tienes al menos 1 valor sobre el cual deseas filtrar los datos. En este caso se trata del nombre del tipo de movimiento.

Lo que se hace es obtener el valor del campo `_id` asociado al documento de la colección `movementTypes` cuyo campo `name` coincide con el filtro aplicado. Una vez obtenido dicho valor, podemos aplicarlo para filtrar los documentos de la colección `movements` y al final usar el método `populate` sobre el campo `movementType`.

En esencia lo que se tiene es lo siguiente:

```js
// Consultamos la colección movementTypes para obtener el valor de _id
// que se corresponda con 'Ingresos'
const movementType = await MovementType.findOne({name: 'Ingresos'});

// Ahora consultamos la colección movements para obtener aquellos documentos
// cuyo campo movementType coincida con el valor de _id obtenido anteriormente
// Nuestro método populate ya no requiere una condición match
const records = await Movement
.find({ user: user_id, movementType: movementType._id })
.populate({
  path: 'movementType'
});

return records;
```

**Usando un proceso de agregación**

También podemos usar un proceso de agregación, mediante las etapas [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html), [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) y [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Esto nos permitirá filtrar los documentos a medida que realizamos la consulta.

Lo primero será escribir nuestro `Array` de agregación, abriendo una etapa `$match` para el campo `user`, donde pasaremos el valor de `user_id`. Debemos recordar que Mongoose no hace el *casting* (conversión de tipos) cuando trabajamos con procesos de agregación, por lo tanto debemos convertir manualmente el valor de `user_id` a un tipo [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html#objectid) válido. Para ello podemos apoyarnos en el método `ObjectId()` del objeto [`Types`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids) de Mongoose.

Un proceso de agregación para esta consulta sería el siguiente:

```js
const agregacion = [
  {
    $match: {
      user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user_id)
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'movementTypes',
      localField: 'movementType',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'movementType'
    }
  },
  { $unwind: '$movementType' },
  { 
    $match: {
      'movementType.name': 'Ingresos'
    }
  }
];

// Ahora usamos el proceso de agregación con el método aggregate de nuestro modelo
const records = await Movement.aggregate(agregacion).exec();

return records;
```

Como se aprecia en el código anterior, hacemos primero un `$match` contra el valor del campo `user`, luego hacemos un `$lookup` sobre la colección `movementTypes` para *poblar* el campo `movementType`, luego hacemos `$unwind` sobre dicho campo, ya que toda etapa `$lookup` devuelve un `array`. Por último hacemos nuevamente una etapa `$match` para filtrar aquellos documentos cuyo campo `movementType.name` sea igual a *Ingresos*.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema y aclare un poco el uso del método `populate` de Mongoose y su verdadero alcance.

Comment: He probado las dos primera soluciones y si me funcionaron como esperaba. Pero, en la 3era solución me devuelve un array vacio :( . Lo que hice luego para probar fue que en el $lockup->from le puse 'movementtypes' todo en minúscula porque así estaba creado en la db pero me devuelve todos los valores sin filtrar el name = Ingresos

Comment: Vale, agrega los nombres de las colecciones a tu pregunta y editaré la respuesta usando una herramienta en linea para que veas el funcionamiento. Saludos

Comment: Correción de mi parte, ya una vez que cambie el nombre de movementTypes por movementtypes ya funcionó correctamente. Muchas gracias enserio :) ya estaba punto de regresar a SQL